# Accessibility: How to style html for Safari text-only zoom

Tags: html, css, safari, accessibility, zooming

In the Safari desktop browser, Option–Command–Plus sign (+) and Option–Command–Minus sign (-) will change the text-only zoom level.  This is an accessibility feature and it's different from the regular zoom feature.

My site looks ok at the default text-only zoom level, but I am not sure how to adjust my CSS when users are zoomed in or out.  Any idea how to detect this feature in Safari?

Btw, this feature is also available in Chrome.

Comment: you don't "detect" this, you just style your page using relative units. Then the user can zoom as much as they like.

Comment: Thanks @cloned.  In general you are right but there are few elements that have width and I don't want the font size to get too large.  If I can set max font-size I think that should help fix my issue.

Comment: If they have width then they can still grow in height. Maybe rethink your approach from design perspective and don't put elements next to each other on smaller breakpoints. Also if the user zooms they are used to websites not looking as nice as in default mode. I zoom from time to time and as long as everything is readable and understandable, I don't care if anything gets "too big."

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct, it sounds like you are trying to adjust the size of the text when the user zooms in or not, correct? If so, are you using REM unit sizing for tags? REM units adjust the sizing of an element based on the zoom of the browser. 1rem = 16px at a zoom level of 100%. If the user zooms to 150%, 1rem would equal 24px. Likewise, you can set an element to 2rem and it will take the 16px multiplied by 2 at 100% zoom. You can also use EM units which take the parent REM multiplied by a value. 1rem = 16px on the parent. .75em on the child means the parent is 16px, but the child is 12px. An example of this is below:

```css
.one-rem {
  font-size: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.two-rem {
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.one-em {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.two-em {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<p class="one-rem">This is a paragraph tag at 1rem</p>
<p class="two-rem">This is a paragraph tag at 2rem</p>
<br><br>
<div class=container>
  This is the container for the em p tags. Container is set to 1.5rem.
  <p class="one-em">This is 1em </p>
  <p class="two-em">This is 2em </p>
</div>
```

This method can be used for other elements too, such as img tags.

Comment: `1rem = 16px` is only true for the default setting. Users can set any value they want as a base value.